# Will ES.SO graduate soon?

Tags: discussion, beta-sites, graduating-sites

Today, Leap Day, marks the 90th day ES.SO has been in beta. It already meets the threshold of 10qpd (questions per day). Should it be graduated?

Comment: I'll ask the community team to weigh in here, but the short version is... "questions per day isn't a hard threshold that immediately flips the site over to graduated".

Comment: Sorry to possibly disappoint you, but at *Movies & TV* we spent over 900 days in Beta...

Comment: At PPCG we spent something like 2,000 days in beta :/

Comment: Also Chemistry spent some 3 years in beta. If I were you I wouldn't think about graduation for another year or two. As Andrew and Downgoat demonstrated, this is somehow the norm. The *exact* criteria for graduation may never be revealed, since the beta should strive to grow, not to game the stats.

Comment: Surely. The non-english SO sites are the [largest and most fast growing ones on the whole network](http://data.stackexchange.com/physics/query/656464/rising-suns). It is a terrible mistake from the SE Inc that they essentially outlawed them.